# Sitecore Speak Visual Studio 2022

Tags: sitecore-client, speak

I need to make a Sitecore Speak application in Visual Studio 2022. Last time I did this in a project in VS2019, I used "Sitecore Rocks" - but I get an error when I try to install Sitecore Rocks in VS2022. It seems it is not compatible.
How do I make Speak applications in Visual Studio 2022?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation is to use Sitecore powershell extensions instead of SPEAK.
https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/interfaces/interactive-dialogs

Comment: Thanks - yes I found out that Sitecore Rocks has not been updated to VS2022 (which is 64bit vs VS2019 which is a 32bit application).
Also, I am not even sure that SPEAK is being maintained with newer versions of Sitecore.
In any case, SPE is not really viable for our use, so we are opting for an aspx page.